# "Authorization code is already claimed" error

Tags: square

I've previously has no issues with re-granting OAuth permissions as you didn't need to revoke access in order to re-grant access.

What could be causing "Authorization code is already claimed"?

I know this error sounds obvious but I can't find documentation on this error and I believe that this shouldn't occur unless the endpoint isn't generating a new Authorization code. I wonder if there needs to be certain amount of time that needs to pass before re-granting access can occur, though I've never ran into this issue when implementing Square Up into my project.

Answer (score 0):

That message implies that the authorization code returned from the [Authorize](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/oauth#get-authorize) endpoint was already used by the [ObtainToken](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/oauth#post-token) endpoint. If you need a new authorization code, you'll need to have the merchant/customer go through the Authorization flow again so that a new authorization code is generated.

With that said, you mention "re-granting" access. To re-grant someone access (who already has access), you shouldn't need to go through the authorization flow (meaning you don't need to use an authorization code). You just need to go through the [RenewToken](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/oauth#post-renew) endpoint which only requires your `client_id` and the `access_token` you want to renew. If they no longer have access (their access was revoked or expired), then you'll need to go through the entire Authorization flow again.

Comment: During development on my project and learning to implement OAuth and client locations, I was actually "re-authorizing" as I was learning the process and I never received this error.

So I was surprised that this error appear for a client. Re-authorizing is not a process I was intending to use in production. The message makes sense but I've never have to revoke a token in order to re-authorize before is all I'm saying.

Comment: I believe these errors are relatively new, as before all OAuth errors were the same generic one so you couldn't pinpoint where the error might be. Furthermore, you do not need to revoke a token ever in order to re-authorize. You just need to use the `RenewToken` endpoint that I referenced above.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue - In my code, I was checking the CURL_EXEC for errors, and then running CURL_EXEC again, thus causing the issue. I just eliminated the error check.

```
if(!curl_exec($curl)){
        return 'Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl);
}

$ch = curl_exec ($curl);
```